# Are there any publically available java collections unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, collections

Tests which i can plug-in my implementation of Set and ListIterator specifically.

Answer (score 9):

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) has a set of `TestSuiteBuilders` that, together, produce between a few hundred and a few thousand test cases for a given collection implementation, in the `guava-testlib` component.  For example, you might write something like

```
public static Test suite() {
  return SetTestSuiteBuilder.using(new TestStringSetGenerator() {
      @Override protected Set<String> create(String[] elements) {
         return ImmutableSet.copyOf(elements);
       }
    })
    .named("ImmutableSet");
    .withFeatures(CollectionSize.ANY, CollectionFeature.KNOWN_ORDER,
        CollectionFeature.SERIALIZABLE,
        CollectionFeature.ALLOWS_NULL_QUERIES)
    .createTestSuite();
}
```

This produces a complete, *extremely* exhaustive set of test cases for the `Set` implementation.

It's not as thoroughly documented as it could be, but it'll get you a *very* exhaustive test suite.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) library provides lots of methods to unit test collections (eg assert that two collections contain the same elements etc). IMHO, it's pretty much an industry standard for this purpose.

Comment: I think you're mistaking the question -- he has custom *implementations* of collections. Those hamcrest matchers will do nothing to test those.